# Deploy Jersey application on Tomcat 8.5

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey

I'm developing a simple application which uses [Jersey](https://jersey.github.io/) as framework to build the API and [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to handle JSON.

When I deploy the application, *by copying & pasting at webapps/*, I can see my index.jsp. Although my created resource isn't reachable, it always show a 404 page. No errors are shown, not event at the catalina.* logs file.

I'm pretty sure about the problem isn't at the java code because it used to work with *.jar include approach. But I'm tired of that and wanted to migrate it to maven architecture.

I won't post my entire code, but [you can see it here](https://github.com/romulets/wso2Example).

To make things easier, here follows the list of dependencies that I'm using:

- jersey-json v1.19
- jersey-server v2.25.1
- jersey-media-json-jackson v2.25.1
- jackson-core v2.9.0
- jackson-module-jaxb-annotations v2.9.0
- jackson-annotations v2.9.0
- jackson-databind v2.9.0
- jackson-jaxrs-base v2.9.0
- ackson-jaxrs-json-provider v2.9.0

What can cause this error? I have nothing to follow, no stack trace, no error message, nothing. Could it be the lack of some dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Get rid of `jersey-json`. That is 1.x and it's going to mess you up
2. You need more than just `jersey-server`. You will also need

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
       <version>2.25.1</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. You should get rid of your web.xml. You don't need it with your `@ApplicationPath` configuration annotation. Also your using a very old schema version in your web.xml. I don't know if that will mess you up either. Better just get rid of the web.xml completely, unless you can find a more up to date header for the file.

Answer (score 0):

not very sure about this but try adding the servlet to your web.xml,
since last time I use jersey i find out it was necesary to communicate with the server

for example this is what I add to a web.xml

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>"PACKAGE WHERE DO YOU HAVE YOUR CLASS"</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Please notice that I was ussing Glassfish server and not Tomcat (in "servlet-class" ), but this migth give you and idea 
I really hope this could help you :)